# how to make a 2d array after multiplying two 1d arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays

The code I have used is below:

```
int m=0;
int n=0;

//to populate the output array
for( int i=0 ; i<3 ;i++)
{
    for(int j=0 ;j<3; j++)
    {
        if(n<3)
        {
            DeltaWhj[m][n] =  deltaO[i][j] *Sh[0][m];
            n++;
        }
        if(m==1 && n<3)
        {
            DeltaWhj[m][n] =  deltaO[i][j] *Sh[0][m];
            n++;
        }
        else
        {
            DeltaWhj[m][n] =  deltaO[i][j] *Sh[0][m];
            n++;
        }
    }
}

for(int i=0 ;i<3 ;i++)
{
    cout<<"\n\n";
    for(int j=0; j<3 ;j++)
    {
        cout<<DeltaWhj[i][j]<<"\t\t";
    }
}
```

Two input arrays are:

```
double deltaO[1][3]={1  , 1 , 1};
double Sh[1][3]={1  , 2  , 1};
```

The output after multiplying deltaO with each element of Sh should be

```
double DeltaWhj[3][3]={
{1  , 1 , 1},
{2  , 2 , 2},
{1  , 1 , 1}};
```

Comment: come up with problem, do not ask for what solution you want.

Comment: @rahul.deshmukhpatil He doesn't ask for a solution, he ask about a solution to his problem. He already provided a code, but doesn't work.

Comment: 1) `m` never update.

Comment: What isn't working? Does it crash? What is the output? Provide more details about the problem please.

Comment: it's crashing whenever i am running it.

Comment: 2) `n` is bigger than 3, more more.

Comment: Btw. why are the input arrays two-dimensional if you say you only need one-dimensional input arrays? (and they have the first dimension set to 1 anyway, so it is not necessary to have that dimension)

Comment: @AjayThakur Am I correct to assume you are looking to make a Tensor product?

Comment: 2 for loops will do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        result[i][j] = Sh[0][i] * deltaO[0][j];
   }
}
```

Also, consider making double `double deltaO[3]` instead of `deltaO[1][3]` and same for `Sh[1][3]`. Consider as well defining a constant for size and working with it instead of magic number 3.